Get exact file size via smbj
I am trying to read files from an SMB share using the smbj library.
My code needs to read into a byte array (see below), and I need to know the file size before reading. Unfortunately when studying the code I can only find methods to get the allocated size, which usually is bigger than the real file size.
So how can I get the actual size of the file in bytes?
My (wrong code) so far looks like this:
    SMBClient client = new SMBClient();
    try(Connection connection = client.connect(hostname)) {
      AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext(user, password.toCharArray(), domain);
      Session session = connection.authenticate(ac);

      // Connect to Share
      try (DiskShare share = (DiskShare) session.connectShare(shareName)) {
          FileAllInformation fileInfo = share.getFileInformation(path);
          File file = share.openFile(path, EnumSet.of(AccessMask.GENERIC_READ), null, SMB2ShareAccess.ALL, SMB2CreateDisposition.FILE_OPEN, null);

          long fileSize = fileInfo.getStandardInformation().getAllocationSize();

          // this part is problematic as it throws an IOException
          // if not the fileSize amount of bytes can be read
          byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(fileIn, fileInfo.getStandardInformation().getAllocationSize());
      }
   }

Why read files into a byte array?
I am writing a protocol plugin for Apache Nutch. And the API expects file content to be provided as byte[].
Why not have IOUtils read the complete file?
The call IOUtils.toByteArray(fileIn) would read the complete file. But it fails with an IOException if the file is bigger than 2 GB. So I'd like to specify the maximum size to read. And here the IOUtils API allows to specify the amount of bytes using IOUtils.toByteArray(fileIn, amount). But the caveat is that now the call will fail if the file is smaller. Thus I need to know the filesize (and thus the amount of bytes I want to read) before making that call.

Why are you reading it into memory at all btw?

Also this: // this partis problematic as it throws an IOException It must be said that most all such IO methods would throw such an exception. If you have to read the file into memory for a legitimate reason, you could probably do something like share.read(byteArrayOutputStream, null) just fine if the size is within bounds

@g00se I updated my answer. And I cannot see the share.read(outputstream, null) method. Where did you find it?

Sorry, I think I was looking at the wrong javadoc. Did you find the current ones? But this works fine for me: byte[] content = null;try (ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();InputStream in = file.getInputStream()) {in.transferTo(out);content = out.toByteArray();}

Did you test with files bigger than 2GB? I believe the limitation comes from Java, not IOUtils.

No, I tested with something of 40 bytes length ;)

File is File{fileId=SMB2FileId{persistentHandle=ec d0 34 96 00 00 00 00}, fileName='\nucsrv.home\bak\goose\XP\win7-installer-usb.img.gz'}
Filesize is 3923768862 [but I wasn't going to read that into memory ;) ]

Looking at their github repo, the remoteCopyTo() function uses this:
long fileSize = getFileInformation(FileStandardInformation.class).getEndOfFile();

So, in your case, you want to try the following:
long fileSize = fileInfo.getStandardInformation().getEndOfFile();

I believe this will give you the actual size.

It does! Thank you. :-)

Why bother with the length?  Can't you just use
byte[] IOUtils.toByteArray(InputStream inputStream)
and let that utility read until the End of File is reached?

You will get an exception when your file length is bigger than 2 GB. I want to prevent reading that much for nothing.
